# Preventing the view part before the data load to component

Tags: angular, angular5

In my service I am requesting a json data from backend. ( json file from local system )

after loading I see the value in the page. but as well getting the error also. it seems that even before my data available my template is trying to get the value.

how to prevent this issue? here is my component code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from './shared/service/server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    data:Object;

    constructor(private server:ServerService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.server.getJSON().subscribe(data => this.data = data );

    }

}
```

here is the error: the same error I see 3 times. as well page renders my value too

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AppComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14635)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11619)
    at eval (core.js:5918)
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing **data:Object;** write **data:Object = {};**

in this case data will be a new object which is not undefined anymore.

Other way is to new you'r object in the onInit function like below

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.data = {};
    this.server.getJSON().subscribe(data => this.data = data );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access name in template use below code.

```
<div *ngIf="data?.name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use ngif until the data is avaliable

```
<div *ngIf="data"> 
   {{data.name}}
</div>
```

EDIT: Another way to use is using a loading flag

```
data:Object;
dataLoading=true;

constructor(private server:ServerService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.server.getJSON().subscribe(data =>{ 
      this.data = data 
      this.dataLoading = false;
    });    
}

<div *ngIf="!dataLoading "> 
   {{data.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I agree. In case of single element we do. a data need to supply in to no.of element than how can we write?

Answer (score -2):

You're probably reading `.name` in your html. I think that would be a best practise to transform your function in a Promise, then you could try usign this:

```js
async ngOnInit(){
        this.data = await this.server.getJSON();
    }
```

BUT, to be more specific, is better to initialize your data object. For example, if you're reading only `name` property, you could do this:

```js
public data: any;

constructor() {
  this.data = {name: null}
}
```

Comment: Using observabale is mostly better than promise .

Comment: then try to initialize your object, should be fine

Comment: It's in my answer ;)